# Clear inside a loop

Tags: infinite-loop

I want to solve a system of differential equations and each time I want to change two parameters. To prevent wrong result I want to clear every assignment after solving the equations in each iteration. I have a `Do`-loop with two iterator. The problem is that if I use `` Clear["Global`*"] `` then the outer iterator will not be accessible to the code inside the loop.

Here is an example:

```
Do[{Print[a]; Clear["Global`*"];}, {a, 1, 2}, {b, 1, 2}]
```

Result:

> ```
> 1
>
> a
>
> 2
>
> a
> ```

As you can see the iterator `a` is erased for the inner iterator `b`. How can I resolve this issue?

I expect the outer iterator to be printed each time. There are 4 iteration in total, so I expect to get:

> ```
> 1
> 1
> 2
> 2
> ```

I want both iterators, a and b, in spite of using Clear command to be accessible to the code inside loop. I want to clear everything after each iteration except iterators a and b.

Comment: What would be your expected result?

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: Perhaps a description and removal of the actual symbol clash would be more effective than dropping the big one. Posting the offending code is often useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
Do[{Print[a];
  Map[Clear, DeleteCases[Names["Global`*"], "a" | "b"]]},
 {a, 1, 2}, {b, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: That gives `1 1 2 2` as well as ``Do[{Print[a]; Quiet@ClearAll["Global`*"];}, {a, 1, 2}, {b, 1, 2}]``. Apparently the OP desires `1 1 1 1`.

Comment: @Öskå I am sorry I was wrong. This answer is what I needed.

Comment: Without clearing `a` and `b` the result *should* be 1 1 2 2.

Comment: Ah, well, `ClearAll` is enough then :)

Comment: As far as I know what I wrote in my first comment works ;o)

Comment: Could someone add Öskå solution to the answer too?

Comment: @yashar It's enough in the comment I guess :)

Comment: @Öskå Could you please explain about the functionality of `Quiet`? In the Mathematica help it's written that this command prevents messages to be generated. I cannot understand the role of this command here.